# Add counter to javascript function loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am quite new to javacript and I am trying to add a numerical counter as a loop to the below function to save me typing it out 8 times!

The Function needs to be called loadPopup1 - loadPopup8 and the #toPopup div needs to be toPopup1 - toPopup8.

Here's my code:

```
function loadPopup() { 
    if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        closeloading(); // fadeout loading
        $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001); 
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
    }   
}
```

Many thanks for your help!

Pete

Answer (score 2):

Hand over a parameter to the function...

```
function loadPopup(index) {
   ...
   $("#toPopup" + index).fadeIn(0500);
   ...
}
```

Then, if you want to act on #1 and #7, call it passing the index...

```
loadPopup(1);
loadPopup(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will create your 8 functions:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
    (function(i) {
        window['loadPopup' + i] = function loadPopup() {
            if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
                closeloading(); // fadeout loading
                $("#toPopup" + i).fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
                $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
                $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001); 
                popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
            }
        };
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadPopup(i) {
    if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        closeloading(); // fadeout loading
        $("#toPopup" + i).fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001);
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
    }
}

var wrapper={};
for (var i =0; i < 8; i++){
    wrapper['loadPopup' + i] = new function(){loadPopup(i);};
}

// so you can call
wrapper.loadPopup3();
```